# Which environmental variables can be used alter control flow and keep suid?

Tags: c

I am working on a challenge where it is possible to manipulate environmental variables (in C).

I know that with `PATH` it is possible to execute arbitrary programs when relative path is used, for example: `execv("ls", 0);`

`export PATH=path/to/attackers/dir/:$PATH` (This works as well by changing the PATH environmental within the program's memory, e.g `char **envp`)

I have read something about `IFS` but I think is only applicable on scripts.

`export IFS=/` (so /bin/ls will become `bin ls`)

Is there any other environmental that can be used for exploitation?

I was trying for example to mess with `PWD` in order to influence `fopen("file")` with a file in different directory than the current but it didn't work. (the `fopen` eventually calls `getcwd` which I could not identify how exactly it operates).

`export PWD=new/pwd` (It changes the prompt but the `pwd` command returns the right current working directory)

Operating system: Ubuntu (latest kernel)

Comment: most of these tricks only apply to shell scripts, not C programs

Answer (score 1):

How exactly did you set the path? Can you confirm the output of `pwd` changes?

> `get_current_dir_name()` will `malloc(3)` an array big enough to hold the absolute pathname of the current working directory. If the environment variable `PWD` is set, and its value is correct, then that value will be returned.

[Source](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd)

Which operating system do you use?

> Under Linux, the function getcwd() is a system call (since 2.1.92).
>          On older systems it would query /proc/self/cwd.
>   Straight from the kernel source:

```
/*
 * NOTE! The user-level library version returns a
 * character pointer. The kernel system call just
 * returns the length of the buffer filled (which
 * includes the ending '\0' character), or a negative
 * error value. So libc would do something like
 *
 *  char *getcwd(char * buf, size_t size)
 *  {
 *      int retval;
 *
 *      retval = sys_getcwd(buf, size);
 *      if (retval >= 0)
 *          return buf;
 *      errno = -retval;
 *      return NULL;
 *  }
 */
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(getcwd, char __user *, buf, unsigned long, size)
{
    int error;
    struct path pwd, root;
    char *page = (char *) __get_free_page(GFP_USER);

    if (!page)
        return -ENOMEM;

    get_fs_root_and_pwd(current->fs, &root, &pwd);

    error = -ENOENT;
    spin_lock(&dcache_lock);
    if (!d_unlinked(pwd.dentry)) {
        unsigned long len;
        struct path tmp = root;
        char *cwd = page + PAGE_SIZE;
        int buflen = PAGE_SIZE;

        prepend(&cwd, &buflen, "\0", 1);
        error = prepend_path(&pwd, &tmp, &cwd, &buflen);
        spin_unlock(&dcache_lock);

        if (error)
            goto out;

        /* Unreachable from current root */
        if (!path_equal(&tmp, &root)) {
            error = prepend_unreachable(&cwd, &buflen);
            if (error)
                goto out;
        }

        error = -ERANGE;
        len = PAGE_SIZE + page - cwd;
        if (len <= size) {
            error = len;
            if (copy_to_user(buf, cwd, len))
                error = -EFAULT;
        }
    } else
        spin_unlock(&dcache_lock);

out:
    path_put(&pwd);
    path_put(&root);
    free_page((unsigned long) page);
    return error;
}
```

TL;DR

glibc only specifies a stub looking up the PWD variable, it it is not set, the filesystem implementation has to handle the job